# Animations do not work in the 2D unit in the language С#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")));
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")));
        anim.SetFloat("MoveY", Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")));
        anim.SetFloat("MoveY", Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")));
    }
}
```

Animations in the unit do not work for me, I think it's because of the code, you can check it and help me solve the problem, I'm new to programming and don't know much

Created an animator controller called it the player added sprites to the animation (made frame by frame) in Unity 2D

Please answer this question

The player must move left, right, forward and backward

Comment: Introduce variables in your code, by looking at it it is obvious that `Mathf.Abs` is doing no good.

Comment: Show us your animator state machine (in particular how the transitions are set up) and the variable list of the animator.

Answer (score 1):

Don`t try to take Animator in Update at first. Use Start function for it.

Then I would suggest taking the input into a separate variable, and then throwing it into a parameter, something like this:

```
m_HorizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
anim.SetFloat("horizontalSpeed", m_HorizontalMovement);
```

And don`t duplicate code like you do in Update function for "MoveX" and "MoveY". You did that twice.;)

If you realy just want player to move `left right up down` try to use player s Transform component and it s `transform.position`.